# React: issues with getting the environment variables with react-native-dotenv

Tags: reactjs, typescript, react-native, babeljs

I have 2 projects, an app and a webapp, the app I already set up with react-native-dotenv and works accordingly. Now using the same code for the webapp results in an error: `Can't resolve '@env'`.

Is there something React does that Expo doesn't which could possibly be causing this?

`src/common/database/index`

```
import { HOSTIP } from "@env"; // Can't resolve '@env'

connectFirestoreEmulator(db, HOSTIP, 8080);
```

`src/common/types/env.d.ts`

```
declare module "@env" {
    export const HOSTIP: string;
}
```

In the root of the project: `babel.config.js`

```
module.exports = function (api) {
    api.cache(true);
    return {
        plugins: [
            [
                "module:react-native-dotenv",
                {
                    moduleName: "@env",
                    path: ".env",
                },
            ],
        ],
    };
};
```

Does anyone have an idea what could be causing this error? The structure is the same as in the app itself, so I'm really grasping for any leads here.

Answer (score 0):

I suppose your webapp is written react instead of react native. In that case, how about using the `dotenv` package? (https://github.com/motdotla/dotenv)

```
# install locally (recommended)
npm install dotenv --save
```

As early as possible in your application, import and configure dotenv:

```
import * as dotenv from 'dotenv'
dotenv.config()
import express from 'express'
```

Then you can access to the key-value pairs from `.env` file:

`src/common/database/index`

```
connectFirestoreEmulator(db, process.env.HOSTIP, 8080);
```